# Has anyone managed to successfully map DMA-coherent memory into usermode on newer X86 kernels

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

## DMA coherent buffers with newer linux kernels then you end up in MMU hell

We have a well running data acquisition system, working with PCIe Busmaster DMA with an AMD/Xilinx Artix FPGA.
The system is running with a kernel module on an X86/AMD64-Kernel 4.19 with/or without xenomai-3 real time patch and also on ARM64 - raspberry pi cm4 - BCM2835 with Kernels 5.10, 5.15 and 6.1 with or without preempt-rt patch.

I try to update the x86/AMD64 - kernel to a newer version 5.10, 5.15 or 6.1, but I am unable to fix the MMU-Issues.

## MMU- Trouble - fixable on ARM64

On both architectures a 4 MB DMA-buffer is allocated with dma_alloc_coherent/dma_alloc_attrs-calls.
After allocation of the buffer the memory will be mapped to the usermode applications logical address space.
The normal mmap call remap_pfn_range (vma,.. ) will only work in older kernels ( 4.19 ), mapping the memory noncached.
On newer Kernels the memory will be mapped to userspace, but the coherency is lost. ( by wrong Pagetable MMU cache settings ? )
If I fill the memory with the CPU, I will always see my CPU filled content, never the updated data from the FPGA on kernels newer than 4.19.
On the ARM64 architecture this can be fixed by changing the **remap_pfn_range**-call to an **dma_mmap_coherent**/**dma_mmap_attrs-call** in the kernel mode mmap-handler.

## MMU- Trouble unfixable on x86/AMD64

On x86/AMD64 **remap_pfn_range** is working on Kernel 4.19. The CPU will "see" the data transferred by the FPGA in the buffer.
It may be that the memory is mapped noncached, so that bus snooping is not used.

On newer kernels ( 5.10,5.15 .., 6.1 ), I will only see the CPU filled content, never the data, transferred by the FPGA.
A change of the **remap_pfn_range**-call to **dma_mmap_coherent/dma_mmap_attrs** on a Xeon(R) CPU E3-1275 v5 @3.60GHz with Intel C230 Chipset will result in a Corrupted page table - kernel crash.

Kernel log Xeon(R) CPU E3-1275 v5 @ 3.60GHz with Intel C230 Chipset:

```
Jun 13 09:21:20 debian-11-rt-xeon kernel: create_context (): 178, open device mode=readwrite
Jun 13 09:21:20 debian-11-rt-xeon kernel: irq_init       (): 299, request_irq(irq_number=145) returns err=0
Jun 13 09:21:20 debian-11-rt-xeon kernel: irq_init       (): 305, calling disable_irq(irq_number=145)
Jun 13 09:21:20 debian-11-rt-xeon kernel: irq_init       (): 308, creating 32 semaphores
Jun 13 09:21:20 debian-11-rt-xeon kernel: fakertdm_open  (): 530, fakertdm_open mode=readwrite called
Jun 13 09:21:20 debian-11-rt-xeon kernel: hpdaq_api      (): 1176, HPDAQ_ALLOCDMA (X86/AMD64) PCIe-DMA #0: kptr=0xffff8ff497800000, phys=0xff400000, size=4194304
Jun 13 09:21:20 debian-11-rt-xeon kernel: hpdaq_map_dma  (): 1795, MAP DMA by dma_mmap_attrs(...)
Jun 13 09:21:20 debian-11-rt-xeon kernel: hpdaq_map_dma  (): 1802, (X86/AMD64 dma_mmap_attrs) MAP DMA #0: kptr=0x7f564478b000, phys=0xff400000, size=4194304
Jun 13 09:21:20 debian-11-rt-xeon kernel: rtflex: Corrupted page table at address 7f564478b000
Jun 13 09:21:20 debian-11-rt-xeon kernel: PGD 800000011c79e067 P4D 800000011c79e067 PUD 133e8d067 PMD 11c469067 PTE 8000ef630478b227
**Jun 13 09:21:20 debian-11-rt-xeon kernel: Bad pagetable: 000f [#1] SMP PTI**
Jun 13 09:21:20 debian-11-rt-xeon kernel: CPU: 2 PID: 7669 Comm: rtflex Tainted: G           OE     5.10.0-23-amd64 #1 Debian 5.10.179-1
Jun 13 09:21:20 debian-11-rt-xeon kernel: Hardware name: Default string Default string/SKYBAY, BIOS 5.12 10/08/2019
Jun 13 09:21:20 debian-11-rt-xeon kernel: RIP: 0033:0x7f567b3506fa
Jun 13 09:21:20 debian-11-rt-xeon kernel: Code: 0f 82 04 01 00 00 48 83 fa 40 77 77 c5 fe 7f 44 17 e0 c5 fe 7f 07 c5 f8 77 c3 66 0f 1f 44 00 00 48 89 d1 40 0f b6 c6 48 89 fa <f3> aa 48 89 d0 c5 f8 77 c3 66 66 2e 0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00 00 66 90
Jun 13 09:21:20 debian-11-rt-xeon kernel: RSP: 002b:00007ffe4372e618 EFLAGS: 00010206
Jun 13 09:21:20 debian-11-rt-xeon kernel: RAX: 00000000000000ff RBX: 000055d6d31230d0 RCX: 0000000000400000
Jun 13 09:21:20 debian-11-rt-xeon kernel: RDX: 00007f564478b000 RSI: 00000000000000ff RDI: 00007f564478b000
Jun 13 09:21:20 debian-11-rt-xeon kernel: RBP: 0000000000000000 R08: 000055d6d3196bf0 R09: 00007f567b3bebe0
Jun 13 09:21:20 debian-11-rt-xeon kernel: R10: 000055d6d3196cc0 R11: 0000000000000000 R12: 0000000000000000
Jun 13 09:21:20 debian-11-rt-xeon kernel: R13: 0000000000400000 R14: 00007ffe4372e670 R15: 000055d6d319bcb0
Jun 13 09:21:20 debian-11-rt-xeon kernel: FS:  00007f567a0f4f80 GS:  0000000000000000
Jun 13 09:21:20 debian-11-rt-xeon kernel: Modules linked in: hpdaq(OE) 8021q garp stp mrp llc bluetooth jitterentropy_rng iptable_nat nf_nat nf_conntrack nf_defrag_ipv6 nf_defrag_ipv4 iptable_mangle drbg ansi_cprng iptable_filter ecdh_generic rfkill ecc intel_rapl_msr intel_rapl_common x86_pkg_temp_thermal coretemp kvm_intel kvm irqbypass ghash_clmulni_intel nls_ascii nls_cp437 vfat fat aesni_intel libaes crypto_simd cryptd glue_helper rapl intel_cstate intel_uncore efi_pstore serio_raw sg ie31200_edac acpi_pad intel_pmc_core evdev fuse configfs efivarfs ip_tables x_tables autofs4 ext4 crc16 mbcache jbd2 raid10 raid456 async_raid6_recov async_memcpy async_pq async_xor async_tx xor raid6_pq libcrc32c crc32c_generic raid1 raid0 multipath linear md_mod hid_generic usbhid hid sd_mod t10_pi crc_t10dif crct10dif_generic i915 crct10dif_pclmul crct10dif_common crc32_pclmul xhci_pci crc32c_intel drm_kms_helper xhci_hcd psmouse cec ahci libahci drm usbcore igb libata dca i2c_algo_bit usb_common e1000e r8169 scsi_mod realtek
Jun 13 09:21:20 debian-11-rt-xeon kernel:  mdio_devres ptp libphy pps_core fan video button [last unloaded: hpdaq]
Jun 13 09:21:20 debian-11-rt-xeon kernel: ---[ end trace 29c144369cecdba4 ]---
Jun 13 09:21:20 debian-11-rt-xeon kernel: RIP: 0033:0x7f567b3506fa
Jun 13 09:21:20 debian-11-rt-xeon kernel: RSP: 002b:00007ffe4372e618 EFLAGS: 00010206
Jun 13 09:21:20 debian-11-rt-xeon kernel: RAX: 00000000000000ff RBX: 000055d6d31230d0 RCX: 0000000000400000
Jun 13 09:21:20 debian-11-rt-xeon kernel: RDX: 00007f564478b000 RSI: 00000000000000ff RDI: 00007f564478b000
Jun 13 09:21:20 debian-11-rt-xeon kernel: RBP: 0000000000000000 R08: 000055d6d3196bf0 R09: 00007f567b3bebe0
Jun 13 09:21:20 debian-11-rt-xeon kernel: R10: 000055d6d3196cc0 R11: 0000000000000000 R12: 0000000000000000
Jun 13 09:21:20 debian-11-rt-xeon kernel: R13: 0000000000400000 R14: 00007ffe4372e670 R15: 000055d6d319bcb0
Jun 13 09:21:20 debian-11-rt-xeon kernel: FS:  00007f567a0f4f80(0000) GS:ffff8ff76dd00000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
Jun 13 09:21:20 debian-11-rt-xeon kernel: CS:  0033 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
Jun 13 09:21:20 debian-11-rt-xeon kernel: CR2: 00007f564478b000 CR3: 000000011c6de003 CR4: 00000000003706e0
Jun 13 09:21:20 debian-11-rt-xeon kernel: DR0: 0000000000000000 DR1: 0000000000000000 DR2: 0000000000000000
Jun 13 09:21:20 debian-11-rt-xeon kernel: DR3: 0000000000000000 DR6: 00000000fffe0ff0 DR7: 0000000000000400
```

On a AMD Ryzen Embedded V2748 (Zen2,8C,@2.9/4.25 GHz) with a **remap_pfn_range**-call in the mmap-handler (Kernel version 5.10, 5.15 .., 6.1 ), the CPU will only "see" the CPU filled content, never the data transferred by the FPGA (wrong Pagetable MMU cache settings ?).
A change of the **remap_pfn_range**-call to **dma_mmap_coherent/dma_mmap_attrs** with different setting of vma->vm_flags will not change the memory view.

On Kernel 4.19 the Bus-Mastering is working well on AMD Ryzen and Xeon-boards.

I have tried different kernel versions. Can it be expected that the problems will be solved ?